# Tkinter window closing, but python script stays running

Tags: python, tkinter

I've tried a variety of things but can't seem to figure this out.

Here's a general overview of my program, which takes an Excel file as an import and outputs a .pdf of charts:

1. Ask user to enter a file name for the outputted file (using Tkinter textbox input)
2. Ask user to select the input file (using askopenfilename)
3. Does a bunch of work with Pandas to analyze data, then plots it with matplotlib and PdfPages
4. Displays a message with Tkinter that says the file was outputted successfully, along with a "Exit" button, which should end the program, but does not.

Here's #1 (separately, I'm wondering how I could modify this code to accept the "Enter" button instead of having to physically click the button):

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Enter a file name for the report")


def getOutputFileName():
    global outputFileName
    outputFileName = textBox.get("1.0",'end-1c')
    print(outputFileName)
    root.quit()
textBox = Text(root, height=1, width = 25)
textBox.pack()

buttonCommit = Button(root, height=5, width=50, text="After entering a file name, click here.", command=lambda: getOutputFileName())
buttonCommit.pack()

root.mainloop()

root.withdraw()
```

Here's #2:

```
filetypes=[("Excel files", ".xlsx .xls")]
file_path = fd.askopenfilename(filetypes=filetypes, title = 'Open the Excel input file')
df = pd.read_excel(file_path) ## Start of Pandas code
```

#3 shouldn't be relevant as it doesn't use Tkinter whatsoever (plus the .pdf is exporting correctly), so here's #4:

```
window = tk.Toplevel() ## Here I tried using root = tk.Tk() but learned that Toplevel() needs to be used for windows after the first?

window.Title = "Success!"
window.geometry("250x170")
T = Text(window, height = 5, width = 52)

successText = "Report successfully generated. The .pdf file was saved to the same location from which you ran this program. You may close the program now."
b1 = Button(window, text = "Exit", command = window.destroy) ## This button DOES close the window, but doesn't close the entire program (i.e. my IDE stays running the script until I force stop)

T.pack()
b1.pack()
T.insert(tk.END, successText)
tk.mainloop()


print("End of program.") ## this is for testing - the program never gets here.
```

Any advice would be amazing. Thank you.

Comment: First of all `window.Title = ...` doesn't do anything useful. Second of all 
 there is a function named `fd.asksaveasfilename`. You can use instead of the `Text` widget. Why not destroy the widgets instead of creating a new window? The `tk.mainloop()` isn't going to end until all tkinter windows are destroyed. When you use `root.withdraw()` ,you just hide the window.

Comment: Please only focus on one question at a time.

Comment: @TheLizzard thanks so much! I deleted the text box input (#1 above) and have used fd.asksaveasfilename instead - this works much better. That said, my program still stays open even after pressing the "Exit" button at the end (#4 above), which is now `b1 = Button(root, text = "Exit", command = root.destroy)`. I put ` root = tk.Tk()` and `root.withdraw()` at the beginning of the file to avoid an empty window when opening/saving files... I then reinitialized at the end with `root=tk.Tk()` and changed all `window` to `root` in #4...

Comment: @JakeK If that solved your problem please post the solution an answer. People might look at this in the future and it might help them :D